# Html form values not getting as typed +php

Tags: php

I have a php page

```
 <table width="i00%" border="0">
     <tr><td>Comments</td>
     <td><label>
       <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
    </label></td></tr</table>
```

I am typing some values in the comment box like this
*

```
first sentence 
second sentence
```

but when i try to echo the comment box value as **echo $_POST['comments'];**
it will out put as

**first sentence second sentence**.

How can i out put it as

```
first sentence 
second sentence
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it through `nl2br()`. Line breaks have no meaning in HTML output.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why its not doing what he wants it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in nl2br() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php